# Ruby: What's the proper syntax for a boolean regex method?

Tags: ruby, regex, syntax

What is the proper syntax for a method that checks a string for a pattern, and returns true or false if the regex matches?

Basic idea:

```
def has_regex?(string)
    pattern = /something/i
    return string =~ pattern
end
```

Use case:

```
if has_regex?("something")
    # woohoo
else
    # nothing found: panic!
end
```

Comment: Your code works as-is, so I don't really see what you're asking

Comment: Haha, my mistake. I didn't debug my code properly. Thanks for pointing out what should have been obvious.

Comment: There's no reason to define `has_regex?`, just do `if "something" =~ /something/i`

Comment: I want the pattern to be in its own method because I'm reusing it in multiple places, and I'd like to avoid declaring a global variable.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you want the put the pattern in a method, you can just do

```
def has_my_pattern(st)
    st =~ /pattern/
end
```

Or, perhaps better, put the pattern in a class variable instead?

Comment: This does not return a boolean value.  @Ryan's answer is correct.

Answer (score 46):

In the question you said:

> ... method that checks a string for a pattern, and returns true or false if the regex matches

As [johannes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2218060/247730) pointed out [`String=~`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) returns `nil` if the pattern did not match and the position in the string where the matched word stared otherwise. Further he states in Ruby everything except `nil` and `false` *behave like* `true`. All of this is right.

However, they are not *exactly* `true` or `false`. Therefore, the last step is to coerce the value to be a `Boolean`. This is achieved by wrapping the result in double bangs returns a `true`.

```
def has_regex?(string)
    !!(string =~ /something/i)
end
```

Comment: Or: `!(string !~ /something/i)`

Comment: For recent versions of Ruby, reference [matthew.tuck's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45095360/2658159)

Answer (score 15):

Your code looks fine, but you could write it even smaller.

The return value of `String#=~` behaves this way:

- `nil` if the pattern did not match
- the position in the string where the matched word started

In Ruby everything except `nil` and `false` behaves like `true` in a conditional statement so you can just write

```
if string=~ pattern
  # do something
else
  # panic
end
```

Comment: Your answer is right for the provided use case, but does not correctly answer the OP's question (which will matter for people coming here). When assigning the result to an ActiveRecord object for example, this is crucial: `Foo.new(admin: (role =~ /admin/)).admin` returns `false` when `role` is "admin", because `=~` returns 0, which is turned into `false` by Rails. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Ruby 2.4 or later, there are `String#match?(regex)` and `Regexp#match?(string)` methods that return booleans without the conversion shenanigans (where they are needed, though they usually aren't), and have improved performance to boot.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#method-i-match-3F

https://blog.cognitohq.com/new-features-in-ruby-2-4/

Answer (score 11):

To make it return true/false switch the position of pattern and string and use case equality ===

```
def has_regex?(string)
    pattern = /something/i
    return pattern === string
end
```

I absolutely needed it to return true boolean value and digged around.
It is actually documented in regexp class http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D

Comment: This is the best solution, however, it should be noted that when `str` is neither a `String` nor a `Symbol`, `regex === str` returns `false` while other solutions posted here that uses `=~` raises a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 9):

For Ruby >= 2.4 or Rails, you can do:

```
 regexp.match?(string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to the String class makes it pretty simple to use:

```
   class String
      def match?(regex)
          !!self.match(regex)
      end
   end
```

I added it to Rails initializer (RAILS_ROOT/config/initializers) and you can call directly from the string:

```
"Something special!".match?(/something/i) #=> true 
"Somethin' special!".match?(/something/i) #=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone's future reference, double bangs are frowned upon from [bbatsov's ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide). Instead of using a double bang, just check if the value **isn't** nil.  If the value isn't nil, it exists.

Instead of doing this:

```
def has_regex?(string)
  !!(string =~ /something/i)
end
```

You can always do this:

```
def has_regex?(string)
  !(string =~ /something/i).nil?
end
```

Comment: Maybe `(string =~ /something/i).present?` so you don't have to invert it?

Comment: I prefer `(string =~ /something/i) != nil` because I find it more readable.

Comment: Note that `present?` is an ActiveSupport method (i.e. part of Rails) and isn't available if you're just using regular Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, so I will answer instead.

Use of ===, as suggested by viljar, is advised against in [the Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide) and will cause Rubocop complaints (under default rules).

I find the most readable way to be:

```
def match?(string)
  !(string =~ /something/i).nil?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wanted this to work generally, and not just for any specific project, I do not want to modify the environment at all.

I was able to get it to work by simply using the return value from the normal `match` method as a conditional.  Tested both the positive and negative case on this sample string:

```
irb(main):014:0> if "123".match(/.2./); puts "worked"; end
worked
=> nil
irb(main):015:0> if "123".match(/.3./); puts "worked"; end
=> nil
```