# What's the best way to append a line to a file unless a similar line already exists?

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a ruby script to update my /etc/hosts file to add an entry to spoof certain hostnames to IP addresses.

the process is that the script does a dig on the hostname (which is given by the user), find some information from the dig output, do another dig on a related hostname and use that IP address in the /etc/hosts file.

Running the script like this:

```
sudo ruby get_staging.rb www.bestbuy.com
```

results in adding an entry in my hosts file for www.bestbuy.com.

Here is the working script:

```
hostname = ARGV[0]

output = %x(dig #{hostname})

new_hostname = output[/CNAME\s(.*CDN.net)/,1]

new_hostname["CDN"] = "CDN-staging"

staging_dns = %x(dig #{new_hostname})

staging_ip = staging_dns[/(\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\d*)/,1]


open('/etc/hosts', 'a') { |f|
  f.puts "#{staging_ip} #{hostname}"
}
```

For some reason, when I modify it to look like this:

```
hostname = ARGV[0]

already_spoofed = false

open('/etc/hosts') { |f| already_spoofed = true if f.grep(/#{Regexp.quote(hostname)}/) }

unless already_spoofed

  output = %x(dig #{hostname})

  new_hostname = output[/CNAME\s(.*CDN.net)/,1]

  new_hostname["CDN"] = "CDN-staging"

  staging_dns = %x(dig #{new_hostname})

  staging_ip = staging_dns[/(\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\d*)/,1]


  open('/etc/hosts', 'a') { |f|
    f.puts "#{staging_ip} #{hostname}"
  }
end
```

it no longer does anything, just fails quietly. What's the right way to do this? It seems like I could open the file just once, and do all my logic inside the first `open()` call but I'm unsure how to do that or if it's the right way to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set already_spoofed like this:

`already_spoofed = open('/etc/hosts').read =~ (/#{hostname}/) ? true : false`

This reads: Set `already_spoofed` to true, if `/etc/hosts` contains `hostname`

The [match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E) operator `=~` returns `nil` (falsy) or the location of the first matching pattern in the string

Comment: Brilliant. This worked. But any clue why it wasn't working before?

Comment: Are you saying f.grep(/#{Regexp.quote(hostname)}/) will always result in true?

Comment: f.grep() appears to always return an array. In ruby only `NilClass` and `false` are falsy. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215303/ruby-whats-the-proper-syntax-for-a-boolean-regex-method
I didn't try but it would probably work if you did `f.grep(...).empty?`